# How to validate array input in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
<input type="text" name="name[2]">
```

I tried validate like this, but didn't work correctly

```
$valid = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    //'name.2' => 'required',
    'name[2]' => 'required',
]);
```

-- Laravel Framework version 5.3.26

Answer (score 5):

A nice way would be using [Form Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation) and creating dynamic rules for your arrays, like this

```
public function rules()
{
  $rules = [
    'name' => 'required|max:255',
  ];

  foreach($this->request->get('items') as $key => $val)
  {
    $rules['items.'.$key] = 'required|max:10';
  }

  return $rules;
}
```

Here's a nice article talking about this: https://ericlbarnes.com/2015/04/04/laravel-array-validation/

Comment: I know that article. I think like my first rule 'name.2'. But didn't work too,,, :(

Answer (score 3):

You may also validate each element of an array. For example, to validate that each e-mail in a given array input field is unique, you may do the following:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
   'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
   'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name', 
]);
```